# Try Catch in object initialization

Tags: c#

I'm reading CSV file which contain date filed
how can i ignore exception when trying to convert to DateTime?

```
        var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);    
        // skip the first line!
        var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(Consts.Delimiter)); 

        return csvLinesData.Select(data => new ReleaseNote
        {
            Version = data[0],
            ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data[1]) // Possible exception

        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Replace `Convert.ToDateTime` with a function that uses `DateTime.TryParse` and returns the date or whatever your "didn't parse" value should be.

Comment: As your title suggets, why not a `try catch`?

Comment: With try catch you will skip all records, not only one

Comment: You can create your own method ConvertToDateTime and use try catch inside and replace by ReleaseDate = ConvertToDateTime(data[1])

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette ok that's also a good idea, didn't think of that.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette: Using try/catch inside a loop is a bad idea. The various `TryParse` methods on .NET's numeric/DateTime types were created to avoid exactly this costly scenario.

Comment: @Cory: I didn't know for try/catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return csvLinesData.Select(data => {
   DateTime d;
   return new ReleaseNote
   {
     Version = data[0],
     ReleaseDate = DateTime.TryParse(data[1], out d) ? d : DateTime.MinValue
   }
}).ToList();
```

You might also put `null` instead of `DateTime.MinValue` if your ReleaseDate property is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

you should use DateTime.TryParse:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
  {
     if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)) 
        Console.WriteLine("  Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, 
                          dateValue, dateValue.Kind);
     else
        Console.WriteLine("  Unable to parse '{0}'.", dateString);
  }
```

Comment: this is helfull information. would suggest a relevant example to OPs scenario as @Volkan Ceylan provided